# Access Denied (Permission Issue) after upgrade 2.0.3 -> 2.0.4

Tags: magento2, upgrade, permissions, access, magento-2.0.3

Upgraded via admin, on composer installed Magento 2, upgrade reports success. Even though logo and menu and styles show, my store front page only displays this message, instead of the usual frontpage images. Everything is vanilla with sample products.

> Error filtering template: Unable to write file into directory /var/www/html/magento2/pub/media/catalog/product/cache/1/small_image/240x300/beff4985b56e3afdbeabfc89641a4582/m/b. Access forbidden.

Answer (score 2):

Someone solve this with permission 644 files and 755 on folders

Others rename their .htacess file to .htacess-old and checked if the problem persist

Answer (score 1):

This message will appear if you run composer update but don't follow up with the `magento setup:upgrade` command. After ensuring that your file permissions are correct after the upgrade, go to the magento webroot and run this command:

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

Depending on your system permissions, you might need to use `sudo`.