# Magento 2: Unable to write file into directory. Access forbidden

Tags: magento2, admin, windows, wamp, magento2.1.6

After upgrading from 2.1.5 to 2.1.6 CE. I'm getting below error on Windows WAMP while saving product on Admin side.

> Unable to write file into directory
>   \D:/wamp/www/magento/pub/media/catalog/product\cache\3cf5799449660ed39031217945ace72a/H/3.
>   Access forbidden.

I tried below but it's for Linux

[Access Denied (Permission Issue) after upgrade 2.0.3 -> 2.0.4](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/108969/access-denied-permission-issue-after-upgrade-2-0-3-2-0-4)

Comment: have u checked after .htacces file at .pub folder

Comment: Hi @AmitBera What to change in `.htaccess`?

Comment: You can refer to this thread: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/91870/magento-2-folder-file-permissions

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I just updated to Magento 2.1.6 on Windows and had this same issue.  I did a little searching and came across a post on Github [here](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/9212).

In a nutshell you need to do two things in vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/View/Asset/Image.php.

The first thing is replace all occurrences of DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR with '/'

The second is edit the getRelativePath function to look like:

```
private function getRelativePath($result)
{
    $prefix = $result == '/' ? $result : '';
    $result = $this->join($result, $this->getModule());
    $result = $this->join($result, $this->getMiscPath());
    $result = $this->join($result, $this->getFilePath());
    return $prefix . $result;
}
```

You need both changes or it won't work.  Just replacing DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR still throws a forbidden error.  Not including the $prefix elements in getRelativePath causes the forbidden error to go away, but product images won't load.

Comment: In magento2.1.7 there is not any such file (vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/View/Asset/Image.php) and I'm having the same issue.
What should I do?

Answer (score 2):

There is a simple way to solve this issue:
in **vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/View/Asset/Image.php:226**
remove the 'DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR'

```
private function getRelativePath($result)
{
$result = $this->join($result, $this->getModule());
$result = $this->join($result, $this->getMiscPath());
$result = $this->join($result, $this->getFilePath());
return $result;
}
```

and:
**/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/View/Asset/Image.php:130**
replace DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR to '/'

```
 private function join($path, $item)
    {
        return trim(
            $path . ($item ? '/' . ltrim($item, '/') : ''),
            '/'
        );
    }
```

PHP accepts both \ and / as valid path separators. So just use / in your code.